# Is it legal to put clips/images of Eye catch of series on my website?

Tags: copyright, internet

Hey so I was kinda thinking of making this website sort of a lookup database like website with a list of all shows and a link to all their eye catches(images or clips). I was just wondering if this was legal ? I assume (or the safest bet) for the most part is that it is not legal i.e would be copyright infringement. But I am not sure. Oh and some of the shows would be international to and not just local (I live in the US).

Comment: You mean like what IMDB does?

Comment: @Dale M yeah something like that but just clips and images of the eye catch if any for the given series/show.